# How to pre select items in react-native-sectioned-multi-select?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a multiple selection list to React Native. It is react-native-sectioned-multi-select.

I used it to input data to form. When inserting data using the selection list, it works fine. No problem. Now, I need to edit form. So, when I load the form, it does not load selected items to the selection list. I used onSelectedItemsChange to load data. But, I'm getting an error. Instead of automatically calling that function, if I call the function using a button, it loads selected items. But, I need to do it without manually clicking a button.

Here is my code regarding the multiple select.

```
             <SectionedMultiSelect
                  items={this.state.items}
                  uniqueKey="id"
                  subKey="subItem"
                  selectText="Select"
                  confirmText="Select"
                  searchPlaceholderText="Search"
                  removeAllText="Clear all"
                  showDropDowns={true}
                  readOnlyHeadings={true}
                  showCancelButton={true}
                  showRemoveAll={true}
                  onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
                  selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}


onSelectedItemsChange = (selectedItems) => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems});
};
```

When I try to automatically setState of selectedItems it gives the error. But, if I set the state of selectedItems by a button press, it works and selected items are displayed.

Can anyone help me in this case?

https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select

```
onSelectedItemsChange
```

Comment: it's hard to say, when we don't see the code.

Comment: @JuniusL. I've updated my question. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the items in async storage. When you edit the form get the items storage and add them to `selectedItems` array.

for example

storage.js

```
// create function for saving items to storage
export const SaveItem = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    console.log('saved');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

// create function for saving items to storage
export const ReadItem = async key => {
  try {
    var result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
};
```

and use the functions to read and save data, using each forms name as a key. like `SaveItem('form1', [23,34,45])`. Import the functions in your components.

```
import { SaveItem, ReadItem } from './storage';

// get items for a form
editForm = key => {
  ReadItem(key).then(res => {
    const selected = JSON.parse(result);

    this.setState({
      selectedItems: selected
    });
  });
};

// save form data using each forms name 
saveItems = (key, value) => {
  const items = JSON.stringify(value);

  SaveItem(key, items)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('saved', res);
    })
    .catch(e => console.warn(e));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have multiple forms. So, I have to save this data for each and every form? When I click on the relevant form, it should load its relevant selected items.

Comment: please see https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/what-is-asyncstorage-in-react-native-and-how-you-to-use-it-with-app-state-manager-1x09-b8c636ce5f6e

Comment: This worked for me!! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: i dont want to display selected items list so how to do that ??

Comment: If you dont want to display selected items list, set showChips prop to false. @MahiGunjal